# How to change the datatype of Django model field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a set of django models as follows

```
class FirstCategory(models.Model):
    first_category = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_category

class SecondCategory(models.Model):
    first_category = models.ForeignKey(FirstCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    second_category = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.second_category
    
class ThirdCategory(models.Model):
    first_category = models.ForeignKey(FirstCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    second_category = models.ForeignKey(SecondCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    third_category = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.third_category

class FinalList(models.Model):
    unique_number = models.BigIntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    
    first_category = models.ForeignKey(FirstCategory, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, db_column="first_category")
    second_category = models.ForeignKey(SecondCategory, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, db_column="second_category")
    third_category = models.ForeignKey(ThirdCategory, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, db_column="third_category")
    
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

When I migrate the models and check the datatypes of the fields in the `FinalList` table I get the following

```
       column_name         |    data_type
---------------------------+-------------------
 third_category            | bigint
 first_category            | bigint
 second_category           | bigint
 unique_number             | bigint
 name                      | character varying
```

I had specified the first, second, and third categories as Character fields. Why is it being migrated as BigInt?

I am trying to implement a chained dropdown in my form. I am following [SimpleBetterThanComplex](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html) tutorial for this

## Edit 1: contents of the migration file

In the migration file, I have the following

```
('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
```

I am not specifying this myself. I think Django creates this as a auto primary field. Could this be affecting the datatypes of the `ForeignKeys`?

Comment: Could you please check your last migration file whether the datatype has changed or not?

Comment: @Mythilydevaraj I tried deleting all the migrations and migrated again. I get the same result

Comment: Did you run migrate command after makemigrations? Could you please share the migration file, the specific fields alone

Comment: @Mythilydevaraj I have edited the question. Should I add the entire migrations file?

Comment: Primary key is auto generated, it will not affect the data types.

Comment: As I mentioned this will be integer field in final table, as it is foreign keys. Inorder to access it's data you can use the specific foreign key name(first_category, second_category ..) from FinalList model in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django itself creates a primary key on each model, automatically named `id`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields

When you creates a `ForeignKey`,  Django creates a new field that  points to the related model primary key (an automatic id in your case). You can specify another primary key with the `primary_key=True` argument in the field.

```py
class FirstCategory(models.Model):
    first_category = models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_category
```

Additionally, Django provides the `pk` shortcut property to access the primary key in a model, regardless of whether it is automatic or manually specified.

Comment: Do I need to add the primary key to second and third category models as well? Or will adding this to the firstcategory will change the other models as well?

Comment: @Sashaank, you nedd add this to the other models (`SecondCategory`, `ThirdCategory`) in order to use his `CharField` on the `ForeingKeys` of `FinalList`.  Each `ForeignKey` references to the related model primary key.